# Poor battery after update to Android 4.0.3

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates, battery-life

I updated my non-rooted Samsung Galaxy S2 from 2.3.5 to 4.0.3.

Now, I recognize a significant decrease in battery lifetime.

Any idea what may cause it and how to get around it?

Comment: This question is extremely hard to answer without any details. At least look at the "Battery" stats in your settings screen and supply some stats on what's using the battery.

Comment: I agree - my intention was to ask if this may be a common problem with that Android version or device.

Comment: Concerning current battery consumption - I see 50% for the screen (allthough it's off for most of the time) and 25% for Android OS and no application with significant consumption.

Comment: It's normal for the screen to use most of the battery, if the Android OS takes a lot even in standby you should probably try a factory reset/clean install.

Comment: This could be caused by WakeLocks (see: [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/)). Please check at least your battery usage screen for the indicators described in that questions answer; if they match, follow the steps there (and let us know here).

Comment: @Izzy: Ah thank you for the hint, but I did a clean install in the meantime and an update to 4.0.4. The battery consumption is back to normal (if one can call this normal that a phone sometimes doesn't even survive a day of usage...)

Comment: @Geziefer Glad you solved the issue! Would you mind to present your solution by answering your own question? That way it's easier to see this Q *is* answered. As for the runtime: Well, it's no longer just a phone, it's rather a pocket computer which can handle phone calls as well. Would you complain if your laptop "dies" after 18h on battery? ;) Still, I hope they can increase the runtime to 7 days at least... Hope dies last.

Comment: @Izzy: well, thing is, I wouldn't call it a solution, if one has to completely reset his phone to get an official update working correctly, that's why the question is not really answered even though I 'solved' it that way.As for the battery, I do know what this little thing is capable of doing, but isn't it a bit like driving a Porsche with a 10l fuel tank?

Comment: I'd consider it better than to sit around and whine "my battery is empty". But OK, up to you. And sure, more powerful batteries wouldn't hurt XD